# Phantomjs zoomFactor - scale rasterization to a specific size

Tags: pdf, svg, phantomjs, rasterizing

I am rasterizing the following simple html+svg+foreignObject html

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!--reset stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://phantomjs.googlecode.com/git-history/cbdd80e98ea1eb29d5d3a9c65c84798b472b59b1/website/reset.css" />
  <style>
  p {
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-size: 15px !important;
  }
  svg {
    outline: 1px solid purple;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body style="height: 1050px; width: 1050px; max-width: 1050px; max-height: 750px;">
    
<svg style="width: 1050px; height: 750px;">
  <foreignobject height="40" requiredfeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility" width="45" x="45" y="45">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <p>Oh when the sun begins to shine.</p>
    </body>
  </foreignobject>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

using this simple rasterization script:

```
webPage = require 'webpage' 
args    = (require 'system').args        
url = args[1]
destination = args[2]

page  = webPage.create()

page.paperSize = width: '10.5in', height: '7.5in', border: '0in'
#page.zoomFactor = 1.991
#page.viewportSize = (width: 1050, height: 75)

page.open url, (status) ->
  if status isnt 'success'
    console.log "Error!", url, status
    return phantom.exit()

  rasterize = -> 
    page.render destination
    console.log "Rasterized", url, "to", destination
    return phantom.exit()
  setTimeout rasterize, 100
```

[image: Chrome displaying svg]

As you can see, the sizing of the single visible element is 1050px x 750px. I would like to rasterize this exactly onto a 10.5in x 7.5in paper size at 100% the size.

My rasterization script does:

```
page.paperSize = width: '10.5in', height: '7.5in', border: '0in'
```

which turns out with a pdf like this:

[image: Improperly scaled]

So that doesn't scale to full-size. I can adjust to full-size by adjusting the zoom factor. experimentally I've found that this works

```
page.zoomFactor = 1.991
```

[image: Properly scaled, font poorly sized]

Now the element scales properly but the fonts are scaled up too much.

How do I take the left/topmost 1050px/750px of the page ans scale it to exactly 10.5inx7.5in on paper while maintaining the original font size?

Comment: Have you found out anything? I also end with strange scale factors that vary between platforms. Very annoying indeed. I get better result when scaling paperSize directly and not the zoomFactor.

Comment: No, I tried to reach out to the developers but I will try again.

Comment: We had some serious problems with the currently offered PhantomJS binaries as well. We just cloned the repo and built Phantom on a Linux machine (Gentoo) which took a while but apart from that ran without any problems. Afther that we had a Beta 2.0 build which solved _all_ our problems. So I recommend you to try this.

Comment: Thanks @vanthome I've had someone suggest that already. Unfortunately, the prospect of building it for windows is pretty scary (I'm pretty short on c experience) and running an out-of-band version is scarier still. At this point I would settle for an explanation of what causes the issue and what the limitations are, so I can just counsel our users on what to avoid.

Comment: An update on this - I've tried phantom 2.0 and [while the problems are different](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13048) there are still problems and still no response from the phantom team

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried with media queries on css?

```js
webPage = require 'webpage'
args = (require 'system').args
url = args[1]
destination = args[2]

page = webPage.create()

page.paperSize = width: '10.5in', height: '7.5in', border: '0in'#
page.zoomFactor = 1.991# page.viewportSize = (width: 1050, height: 75)

page.open url, (status) - >
  if status isnt 'success'
console.log "Error!", url, status
return phantom.exit()

rasterize = - >
  page.render destination
console.log "Rasterized", url, "to", destination
return phantom.exit()
setTimeout rasterize, 100
```

```css
@media print {
  body {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: none;
    height: 10.5in;
    width: 7.5in;
  }
}
p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 8pt !important;
}
svg {
  outline: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://phantomjs.googlecode.com/git-history/cbdd80e98ea1eb29d5d3a9c65c84798b472b59b1/website/reset.css" />

<body style="height: 1050px; width: 1050px; max-width: 1050px; max-height: 750px;">

  <svg style="width: 1050px; height: 750px;">
    <foreignobject height="40" requiredfeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility" width="45" x="45" y="45">

      <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <p>Oh when the sun begins to shine.</p>
      </body>
    </foreignobject>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: I appreciate the idea. You can do all sorts of stuff with media queries unfortunately that doesn't really help with zoomFactor which seems to affect png and pdf rasterization differently